# Scrolling UITableView to specific position using setContentOffset not working properly - ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I saw many answers in SO which describes how can I scroll UITableView to the specific position.

I use `setContentOffset` for scrolling to particular position.

I meet a weird issue. If my `tableView` is half scrolled then `setContentOffset` is working properly. But when I scroll to end of the `tableView` and then use `setContentOffset`, table view scrolls a little bit more.

My `setContentOffset` value is `CGPoint(0,199)`.

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,199) animated:NO];
```

After reaching a bottom I use `setContentOffset`. Then I check the `contentOffset` of `UITableView`. and it is `169`.

I am not able to figure it out what exactly the issue is.

Edit::

I am using the following code. When a button in the last cell is pressed:

```
- (void)userPressedSubmitButtonOnLastCell
{

[self updateData];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self performSelector:@selector(scrollTableView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}

- (void)scrollTableView
{
 [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,199) animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Make sure your `constraints` are proper

Comment: Yes my constraints are proper @Janesh

Comment: Update your question with scrollView delegate code

Comment: @karthikeyan I haven't  used scroll view.

Comment: then where are you setting setContentOffset code and how are you finding table view scrolled bottom, UITableview is an subview of UIScrollView

Comment: It's a subclass, not a subview.

Comment: I'm guessing this is an issue with the height calculation of your cells. Are you setting both `self.tableView.rowHeight` and `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight` ?

Comment: @Koen yes I am using both. How can I solve this issue.

Comment: Please provide more code, otherwise it is very difficult to guess what you need to do.

Comment: @Koen I have a table view with Header in it. and approx 10-15 cells with dynamic height. In some cells their is a button. On click of that button I need to reload the table and scroll to top showing 10% of header only. I am updating the question.

Comment: Please put all this additional info in your question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)`? This will allow you to scroll to either specific row or rectangle. `ContentOffset` is more suitable for `UIScrollView`.

Comment: In bottom of my table view(in last row) their is a `UIButton`. On click of that button I need to scroll table view at the top. I can't use `tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:` because I have a header (table view header) also. And I need to show some part of Header also.

Comment: I thought your question was about scrolling to the bottom, not to the top?

Comment: I think you can use 'tableView scrollRectToVisible:' and set rect y = 0, so that it will scroll to top of the table